# How to build mysql 5.6 table without alter schema

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5

We upgraded mysql from 5.5 to 5.6 but in mysql 5.6 i can't use **ALGORITHAM= INPLACE** if table build in mysql 5.5 and consist Datetime or time datatype, So i want to rebuild my table in mysql 5.6, is there any other way to rebuild table without using ALTER Command or Copy data from one place to another place.

Comment: If you run `ALTER TABLE tbl_name FORCE`, *once* on the table, subsequent use of `ALTORITHM=INPLACE` will work.  It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve.